# Docker copies the file but doesnt exist while running

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

When i try to build the Dockerfile, it copies the `sample.pdf` from `documents` folder. But the pdf file doesnt exist in container when i run it.

```
Step 6/9 : COPY . .
 ---> b0c137c4b5bb
Step 7/9 : COPY documents/ /usr/src/app/documents/
 ---> 77ac91c3ebb9
Step 8/9 : RUN ls -la /usr/src/app/documents/*
 ---> Running in 03c9f14669c3
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          2830 May  3 14:30 /usr/src/app/documents/sample.pdf
Removing intermediate container 03c9f14669c3
```

After running the docker-compose image.
The image doesnt exist in container.

```
sudo docker exec -it test_consumer_1 ls /usr/src/app/documents
//[None] - it should show sample.pdf
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine


COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Without this setting, Python never prints anything out.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY . .
COPY documents/ /usr/src/app/documents/
RUN ls -la /usr/src/app/documents/*

CMD ["python", "receive.py"]
```

Comment: When you run the image, are you hiding that directory using a volume or bind mount?

Comment: No. Its the simple directory not behind a volume or bind mount as of now

Comment: Are you using a .dockerignore file?

Comment: No, i'm not using it.